# How to make task from asyc

Tags: c#, rest, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a call I need to wait to finish to proceed.  This is a begincreate for an opportunitySet and I'm having issues converting this into a task to wait for.

```
_context.BeginSaveChanges(OnCreateOpportunityComplete, _context.OpportunitySet);


/// <summary>
/// Callback method invoked when Account is done being created.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="result"></param>
private void OnCreateOpportunityComplete(IAsyncResult result)
{
    try
    {
        _context.EndSaveChanges(result);
        Opportunity createdOpportunity = result.AsyncState as Opportunity;
        BeginRetrieveOpportunity(createdOpportunity.OpportunityId);
    }
    catch (SystemException se)
    {
        _syncContext.Send(new SendOrPostCallback(showErrorDetails), se);
    }
}

private void BeginRetrieveOpportunity(Guid _id)
{
    try
    {
        DataServiceQuery<Opportunity> query = (DataServiceQuery<Opportunity>)_context
                .OpportunitySet.Where<Opportunity>(o => o.OpportunityId == _id);
            query.BeginExecute(OnRetrieveOpportunityComplete, query);

    }
    catch (DataServiceQueryException dsqe)
    {
        _syncContext.Send(new SendOrPostCallback(showErrorDetails), dsqe);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to handle this? I've tried numerous times and there seems to be some issues when creating the task. Or if there is any other way for this to wait for the multiple opportunities in the set to be created that would be awesome too.

EDIT: To clarify, the first line in the code is a line in my main function where after I gather all the opportunities I want to add I call the create methods to call the inserts provided in the CRM kit.  This does insert, but by the time the program reaches its end more often than not all of the opportunities have not been created.

Comment: Have you looked at TaskFactory's .FromAsync method?

Comment: That's what I initially tried but was having issues with creating the task. Initialization was giving me trouble then when I thought I had it I get "The non-generic type 'MySolution.ServiceReference.Task' cannot be used with type arguments"...

Answer (score -1):

When making your method, make sure to mark it as "async". Then when calling it don't use the keyword "await" and you will get the its Task. From their you can call yourTask.Wait(). Which will wait until the execution of that method has finalized.

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't really tell what method that you wanted to make `async` because your question is a little unclear, but if you follow this simple method, you should be able to make your own `async` method. Let's say you start with this method:

```
private int DoSomething(int someValue)
{
    ...
}
```

We can run it with `async` in this way:

```
private async int DoSomethingAsync(int someValue)
{
    int result = await Task.Run(() => DoSomething(someValue));
    // Do something with result here when it arrives
}
```

---

UPDATE >>>

You can use the [`Task.Wait` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.wait%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) in Silverlight. If you take a look at the [How to: Wait on One or More Tasks to Complete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537610%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN, you can get an idea of how it is done. This page is only for .NET 4 and 4.5 so I don't know if it will all work with Silverlight but you can try. You can still use your method in a `Task` like I showed you in the example above.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm running VS 2010 and async seems to not be as robust as the later versions of VS.

Comment: Also using Silverlight 4